# security preference in php, php functions to sanitize input

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have the following function that sanitizes input from the user or the url:

```
   function SanitizeString($var)
   {
       $var=stripslashes($var);
       $var=htmlentities($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
       $var=strip_tags($var);
       return $var;
   }
```

I dont know whether to use that function in addition to this php function:

mysql_real_escape_string()..

I also dont know if I take all the precautions to sanitize that input

I also have a problem of stripping tags..cause I am using tiny_MCE..and not stripping them is important..

How do I return the state of the html characters as html characters before they were feed into the database?

Comment: That is very funny, `mysql_real_escape_string` is the only one you need for database, then if you need to output it use `htmlspecialchars` or something similar.

Comment: You can tell that it's not a very appropriate function from the lack of comments.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've been told more than once before; I had a quick glance at your previous questions and many has this function, and you're not still convinced. DON'T SANITIZE HTML BEFORE INSERTING INTO A DATABASE. Just avoid SQL injections. SANITIZE HTML ON OUTPUT.

Comment: how do I decode the whole thing once it is out? I get this <p> dafafa</p>.. I want p represent html character and not a literal. What do you mean by output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about how to sanitize the HTML that comes out before you put it on the screen (which you don't really mention in your question but do in your comments), it's far more complicated than you might think.

Take a look at:
http://iamcal.com/publish/articles/php/processing_html/
and
http://www.iamcal.com/publish/articles/php/processing_html_part_2/

Answer (score 2):

Sanitizing inputs *a priori*, no matter what, is wrong. What does stripping tags has to do with databases? Since when malicious scripts run inside a database?
Being overprecautius is a good thing, except when you do it without a logic.

Sanitize only according to where the "suspect" content need to go.

A database? then escape for the database, to avoid SQL injections. Use [**`mysql_real_escape_string()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or parametrized queries and you're set.

Html page? Sanitize your html to avoid XSS and other nasty things. Use [**`htmlentities()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php), or other more sophisticated solutions, but do that JUST BEFORE OUTPUTTING.

What if you save an html page inside your db, and you strip all tags instead (btw, strip_tags() does this job badly, and calling it after [**`htmlentities()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) is not the best thing)? What if you later need the html back? Just think about it, what harm does to a database the use of the `<script>` tag, or a link to a malaware? Aren't they harmful only when they're printed on a page?

To decode form htmlentities(), just use..[**`html_entity_decode()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: Are you my long-lost twin? ;)

Comment: true..so how do I solve that Issue with TinyMCE...I do want the tags to be printed out and avoid htmlEntities..but I am in danger of being sql attacked ..whats the solution

Comment: Do you each have one half of a medallion?

Comment: I updated, use html_entity_decode(). Anyway, all of this HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH DATABASE SECURITY. For databases use the usual functions, mysql_real_escape_string() or PDO and parametrized queries. IT'S A WHOLE DIFFERENT THING.

Comment: how does decoding work? if I decode it , the hackers code will be executed whatever it is javascript or sql attack

Comment: stop mixing the two things. Anyway, html needs special treatment in order to be representable and safe; none of this is what you're using, but it's mostly removing or changing bad content (script tags, for example)

Answer (score 0):

When storing something in a (MYSQL) database, you'll want to use `mysql_real_escape_string`. If you're using PDO and prepared statements, PDO will take care of escaping for you. This protects you from SQL injection attacks.

When you print user generated content (texts, comments etc), you'll want to use either `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentitites` or the like before you output anything. Which one is appropriate depends on your use case. Whichever you decide on, you'll only need one. This will protect you from XSS attacks.

You never need `stripslashes` etc. as long as [magic quotes are disabled](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Comment: if I use htmlentities from the input I got form the Tiny_MCE..then I will get something like this... <p>one</p> <strong>two</strong> instead of one being in paragraph and two being bold..

Comment: As I said: it depends on your use case. If you want your users to be able to post HTML, you'll have to let them. Be cautious though.

Comment: lol..the question is how do I acheive user satisfaction and security..Thats my whole question

Comment: Perhaps you should have mentioned that in your question, then. Plenty of people have answered what you actually asked. The *really* simple answer to "how do I get HTML on the screen" is to *not* use htmlspecialchars or htmlentities. But check my answer below for more information.